# Popup With Text Only onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog

I have a tab "About" in my onOptionsItemSelected dropdown I want popup box to appear with a few lines of text info about the app when you click "About"

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use or extend the DialogFragment class.

Comment: Thanks that has pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dip">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/app_descrip"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/about_credits"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="@string/app_credits"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Inflate the layout

```
  protected void about() {

        View messageView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about, null, false);


    TextView textView = (TextView) messageView.findViewById(R.id.about_credits);
    int defaultColor = textView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
    textView.setTextColor(defaultColor);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setView(messageView);
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

Call it on menu click